# Reading an Excel file in PHP

Tags: php, import-from-excel

I'm trying to read an Excel file (Office 2003). There is an Excel file that needs to be uploaded and its contents parsed.

Via Google, I can only find answers to these related (and insufficient topics): generating Excel files, reading Excel XML files, reading Excel CSV files, or incomplete abandoned projects. I own Office 2003 so if I need any files from there, they are available. It's installed on my box but isn't and can't be installed on my shared host.

**Edit:** so far all answers point to [PHP-ExcelReader](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/) and/or [this additional article](https://devzone.zend.com/27/reading-and-writing-spreadsheets-with-php/) about how to use it.

Comment: [Zend Article](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3336-Reading-and-Writing-Spreadsheets-with-PHP)

Comment: The two links on the Edit are broken!

Comment: Just as an update PhpSpreadsheet in https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet  is the library used for this now

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I use [PHP-ExcelReader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/) to read xls files, and works great.

Comment: It not working for me i have php 5.2+ , give me error "Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated"

Comment: Same here @hRaval, did u find any solution for it later ??

Comment: Hey guys, I fixed a few things to make it compatible with recent PHP 5 versions:

http://pastebin.com/YNUZANcs

All credits go to the original developers.

Comment: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated"

Comment: As I understand it, PHP-ExcelReader is one class that can handle .xls-files, but not .xlsx files. PHPExcel can handle a lot of different formats (including .xls and .xlsx) (https://github.com/PHPOffice/Phpexcel) and is in stable version. PHPSpreadsheet is a further development of PHPExcel but is not stable (as I'm writing this): https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: Just added small fix to #Lars version for compatibility with php7 https://pastebin.com/qzMnryYN

Comment: PHP-ExcelReader has been deprecated by [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet).

Answer (score 62):

You have 2 choices as far as I know:

1. [Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/), which knows the Office 2003 binary format
2. [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel), which knows both Office 2003 as well as Excel 2007 (XML). (Follow the link, and you'll see they upgraded this library to [PHPSpreadSheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet))

PHPExcel uses Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader for the Office 2003 format.

Update: I once had to read some Excel files but I used the Office 2003 XML format in order to read them and told the people that were using the application to save and upload only that type of Excel file.

Comment: @NTulip: I see nothing in the feature lists or documentation of either to suggest that they can read from Excel files. Any examples?

Comment: @Dinah, you're right. I made the appropriate changes in my response.

Comment: PHPExcel has always been able to read and to write a range of spreadsheet formats. Quoting from the first non-heading line of the home page: "Project providing a set of classes for the PHP programming language, which allow you to __write to__ and __read from__ different file formats, like Excel 2007, PDF, HTML" (my emphasis)

Answer (score 32):

Read XLSX (Excel 2003+)
https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexlsx

```php
if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse('book.xlsx') ) {
    print_r( $xlsx->rows() );
} else {
    echo SimpleXLSX::parseError();
}
```

Output

```
Array (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ISBN
            [1] => title
            [2] => author
            [3] => publisher
            [4] => ctry
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 618260307
            [1] => The Hobbit
            [2] => J. R. R. Tolkien
            [3] => Houghton Mifflin
            [4] => USA
       )

)
```

Read XLS (Excel 97-2003)
https://github.com/shuchkin/simplexls

```php
if ( $xls = SimpleXLS::parse('book.xls') ) {
    print_r( $xls->rows() );
} else {
    echo SimpleXLS::parseError();
}
```

CSV php reader
https://github.com/shuchkin/simplecsv

```php
if ( $csv = SimpleCSV::import('book.csv') ) {
    print_r( $csv );
}
```

Comment: This is the answer that solved my problem using PHP7

Answer (score 22):

It depends on how you want to use the data in the excel file. If you want to import it into mysql, you could simply save it as a CSV formatted file and then use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to parse it.

Answer (score 5):

```
// Here is the simple code using COM object in PHP
class Excel_ReadWrite{

    private $XLSHandle;
    private $WrkBksHandle;
    private $xlBook;

    function __construct() {
        $this->XLSHandle = new COM("excel.application") or die("ERROR: Unable to instantaniate COM!\r\n"); 
    }

    function __destruct(){
        //if already existing file is opened
        if($this->WrkBksHandle != null)
        {   
            $this->WrkBksHandle->Close(True);
            unset($this->WrkBksHandle);
            $this->XLSHandle->Workbooks->Close();
        }
        //if created new xls file
        if($this->xlBook != null)
        {
            $this->xlBook->Close(True);
            unset($this->xlBook);
        }
        //Quit Excel Application
        $this->XLSHandle->Quit();
        unset($this->XLSHandle);
    }

    public function OpenFile($FilePath)
    {
        $this->WrkBksHandle = $this->XLSHandle->Workbooks->Open($FilePath);
    }

    public function ReadData($RowNo, $ClmNo)
    {
       $Value = $this->XLSHandle->ActiveSheet->Cells($RowNo, $ClmNo)->Value;
       return $Value;
    }  

    public function SaveOpenedFile()
    {
        $this->WrkBksHandle->Save(); 
    }  

    /***********************************************************************************
    * Function Name:- WriteToXlsFile() will write data based on row and column numbers
    * @Param:- $CellData- cell data
    * @Param:- $RowNumber- xlsx file row number
    * @Param:- $ColumnNumber- xlsx file column numbers
   ************************************************************************************/
   function WriteToXlsFile($CellData, $RowNumber, $ColumnNumber)
   {
       try{
               $this->XLSHandle->ActiveSheet->Cells($RowNumber,$ColumnNumber)->Value = $CellData;
           }
       catch(Exception $e){
               throw new Exception("Error:- Unable to write data to xlsx sheet");
           }
   }


   /****************************************************************************************
    * Function Name:- CreateXlsFileWithClmName() will initialize xls file with column Names
    * @Param:- $XlsColumnNames- Array of columns data
    * @Param:- $XlsColumnWidth- Array of columns width
   *******************************************************************************************/
   function CreateXlsFileWithClmNameAndWidth($WorkSheetName = "Raman", $XlsColumnNames = null, $XlsColumnWidth = null)
   {
       //Hide MS Excel application window
       $this->XLSHandle->Visible = 0;
       //Create new document
       $this->xlBook = $this->XLSHandle->Workbooks->Add();

       //Create Sheet 1
       $this->xlBook->Worksheets(1)->Name = $WorkSheetName;
       $this->xlBook->Worksheets(1)->Select;

       if($XlsColumnWidth != null)
       {
           //$XlsColumnWidth = array("A1"=>15,"B1"=>20);
           foreach($XlsColumnWidth as $Clm=>$Width)
           {
               //Set Columns Width
               $this->XLSHandle->ActiveSheet->Range($Clm.":".$Clm)->ColumnWidth = $Width;
           }    
       }
       if($XlsColumnNames != null)
       {
           //$XlsColumnNames = array("FirstColumnName"=>1, "SecondColumnName"=>2);
           foreach($XlsColumnNames as $ClmName=>$ClmNumber)
           {
               // Cells(Row,Column)
               $this->XLSHandle->ActiveSheet->Cells(1,$ClmNumber)->Value = $ClmName;
               $this->XLSHandle->ActiveSheet->Cells(1,$ClmNumber)->Font->Bold = True;
               $this->XLSHandle->ActiveSheet->Cells(1,$ClmNumber)->Interior->ColorIndex = "15";
           }
       }
   }
   //56 is for xls 8
    public function SaveCreatedFile($FileName, $FileFormat = 56)
    {
        $this->xlBook->SaveAs($FileName, $FileFormat);
    }

    public function MakeFileVisible()
    {
       //Hide MS Excel application window`enter code here`
       $this->XLSHandle->Visible = 1;
    }
}//end of EXCEL class
```

Comment: This looks good if your PHP server is running on Windows and Excel is installed.

Answer (score 4):

Try this...

I have used following code to read "xls and xlsx"

```
    <?php
    include 'excel_reader.php';       // include the class
    $excel = new PhpExcelReader;      // creates object instance of the class
    $excel->read('excel_file.xls');   // reads and stores the excel file data

    // Test to see the excel data stored in $sheets property
    echo '<pre>';
    var_export($excel->sheets);

    echo '</pre>';

    or 

 echo '<pre>';
    print_r($excel->sheets);

    echo '</pre>';
```

Reference:http://coursesweb.net/php-mysql/read-excel-file-data-php_pc

Comment: It doesn`t recognize the Persian language

Comment: @deenandhayalan can i get the excel_reader.php library?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using below excel file url: https://github.com/inventorbala/Sample-Excel-files/blob/master/sample-excel-files.xlsx

Output:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [store_id] => 3716
                [employee_uid] => 664368
                [opus_id] => zh901j
                [item_description] => PRE ATT $75 PNLS 90EXP
                [opus_transaction_date] => 2019-10-18
                [opus_transaction_num] => X2MBV1DJKSLQW
                [opus_invoice_num] => O3716IN3409
                [customer_name] => BILL PHILLIPS
                [mobile_num] => 4052380136
                [opus_amount] => 75
                [rq4_amount] => 0
                [difference] => -75
                [ocomment] => Re-Upload: We need RQ4 transaction for October.  If you're unable to provide the October invoice, it will be counted as EPin shortage.
                [mark_delete] => 0
                [upload_date] => 2019-10-20
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [store_id] => 2710
                [employee_uid] => 75899
                [opus_id] => dc288t
                [item_description] => PRE ATT $50 PNLS 90EXP
                [opus_transaction_date] => 2019-10-18
                [opus_transaction_num] => XJ90419JKT9R9
                [opus_invoice_num] => M2710IN868
                [customer_name] => CALEB MENDEZ
                [mobile_num] => 6517672079
                [opus_amount] => 50
                [rq4_amount] => 0
                [difference] => -50
                [ocomment] => No Response.  Re-Upload
                [mark_delete] => 0
                [upload_date] => 2019-10-20
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [store_id] => 0136
                [employee_uid] => 70167
                [opus_id] => fv766x
                [item_description] => PRE ATT $50 PNLS 90EXP
                [opus_transaction_date] => 2019-10-18
                [opus_transaction_num] => XQ57316JKST1V
                [opus_invoice_num] => GONZABP25622
                [customer_name] => FAUSTINA CASTILLO
                [mobile_num] => 8302638628
                [opus_amount] => 100
                [rq4_amount] => 50
                [difference] => -50
                [ocomment] => Re-Upload: We have been charged in opus for $100. Provide RQ4 invoice number for remaining amount
                [mark_delete] => 0
                [upload_date] => 2019-10-20
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [store_id] => 3264
                [employee_uid] => 23723
                [opus_id] => aa297h
                [item_description] => PRE ATT $25 PNLS 90EXP
                [opus_transaction_date] => 2019-10-19
                [opus_transaction_num] => XR1181HJKW9MP
                [opus_invoice_num] => C3264IN1588
                [customer_name] => SOPHAT VANN
                [mobile_num] => 9494668372
                [opus_amount] => 70
                [rq4_amount] => 25
                [difference] => -45
                [ocomment] => No Response.  Re-Upload
                [mark_delete] => 0
                [upload_date] => 2019-10-20
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [store_id] => 4166
                [employee_uid] => 568494
                [opus_id] => ab7598
                [item_description] => PRE ATT $40 RTR
                [opus_transaction_date] => 2019-10-20
                [opus_transaction_num] => X8F58P3JL2RFU
                [opus_invoice_num] => I4166IN2481
                [customer_name] => KELLY MC GUIRE
                [mobile_num] => 6189468180
                [opus_amount] => 40
                [rq4_amount] => 0
                [difference] => -40
                [ocomment] => Re-Upload: The invoice number that you provided (I4166IN2481) belongs to September transaction.  We need RQ4 transaction for October.  If you're unable to provide the October invoice, it will be counted as EPin shortage.
                [mark_delete] => 0
                [upload_date] => 2019-10-21
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [store_id] => 4508
                [employee_uid] => 552502
                [opus_id] => ec850x
                [item_description] => $30 RTR
                [opus_transaction_date] => 2019-10-20
                [opus_transaction_num] => XPL7M1BJL1W5D
                [opus_invoice_num] => M4508IN6024
                [customer_name] => PREPAID CUSTOMER
                [mobile_num] => 6019109730
                [opus_amount] => 30
                [rq4_amount] => 0
                [difference] => -30
                [ocomment] => Re-Upload: The invoice number you provided (M4508IN7217) belongs to a different phone number.  We need RQ4 transaction for the phone number in question.  If you're unable to provide the RQ4 invoice for this transaction, it will be counted as EPin shortage.
                [mark_delete] => 0
                [upload_date] => 2019-10-21
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [store_id] => 3904
                [employee_uid] => 35818
                [opus_id] => tj539j
                [item_description] => PRE $45 PAYG PINLESS REFILL
                [opus_transaction_date] => 2019-10-20
                [opus_transaction_num] => XM1PZQSJL215F
                [opus_invoice_num] => N3904IN1410
                [customer_name] => DORTHY JONES
                [mobile_num] => 3365982631
                [opus_amount] => 90
                [rq4_amount] => 45
                [difference] => -45
                [ocomment] => Re-Upload: Please email the details to Treasury and confirm
                [mark_delete] => 0
                [upload_date] => 2019-10-21
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [store_id] => 1820
                [employee_uid] => 59883
                [opus_id] => cb9406
                [item_description] => PRE ATT $25 PNLS 90EXP
                [opus_transaction_date] => 2019-10-20
                [opus_transaction_num] => XTBJO14JL25OE
                [opus_invoice_num] => SEVIEIN19013
                [customer_name] => RON NELSON
                [mobile_num] => 8653821076
                [opus_amount] => 25
                [rq4_amount] => 5
                [difference] => -20
                [ocomment] => Re-Upload: We have been charged in opus for $25. Provide RQ4 invoice number for remaining amount
                [mark_delete] => 0
                [upload_date] => 2019-10-21
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [store_id] => 0178
                [employee_uid] => 572547
                [opus_id] => ms5674
                [item_description] => PRE $45 PAYG PINLESS REFILL
                [opus_transaction_date] => 2019-10-21
                [opus_transaction_num] => XT29916JL4S69
                [opus_invoice_num] => T0178BP1590
                [customer_name] => GABRIEL LONGORIA JR
                [mobile_num] => 4322133450
                [opus_amount] => 45
                [rq4_amount] => 0
                [difference] => -45
                [ocomment] => Re-Upload: Please email the details to Treasury and confirm
                [mark_delete] => 0
                [upload_date] => 2019-10-22
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [store_id] => 2180
                [employee_uid] => 7842
                [opus_id] => lm854y
                [item_description] => $30 RTR
                [opus_transaction_date] => 2019-10-21
                [opus_transaction_num] => XC9U712JL4LA4
                [opus_invoice_num] => KETERIN1836
                [customer_name] => PETE JABLONSKI
                [mobile_num] => 9374092680
                [opus_amount] => 30
                [rq4_amount] => 40
                [difference] => 10
                [ocomment] => Re-Upload: Credit the remaining balance to customers account in OPUS and email confirmation to Treasury
                [mark_delete] => 0
                [upload_date] => 2019-10-22
            )


      .
      .
      .
 [63] => Array
            (
                [store_id] => 0175
                [employee_uid] => 33738
                [opus_id] => ph5953
                [item_description] => PRE ATT $40 RTR
                [opus_transaction_date] => 2019-10-21
                [opus_transaction_num] => XE5N31DJL51RA
                [opus_invoice_num] => T0175IN4563
                [customer_name] => WILLIE TAYLOR
                [mobile_num] => 6822701188
                [opus_amount] => 40
                [rq4_amount] => 50
                [difference] => 10
                [ocomment] => Re-Upload: Credit the remaining balance to customers account in OPUS and email confirmation to Treasury
                [mark_delete] => 0
                [upload_date] => 2019-10-22
            ) 

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have used following code to read "xls and xlsx" :**

```
    include 'PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

    $location='sample-excel-files.xlsx';

    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($location);
    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);
    $total_rows = $sheet->getHighestRow();
    $total_columns = $sheet->getHighestColumn();
    $set_excel_query_all=array();
    for($row =2; $row <= $total_rows; $row++) {
        $singlerow = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $total_columns . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
        $single_row=$singlerow[0];
        $set_excel_query['store_id']=$single_row[0];
        $set_excel_query['employee_uid']=$single_row[1];
        $set_excel_query['opus_id']=$single_row[2];
        $set_excel_query['item_description']=$single_row[3];
        if($single_row[4])
        {
            $set_excel_query['opus_transaction_date']= date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($single_row[4]));
        }
        $set_excel_query['opus_transaction_num']=$single_row[5];
        $set_excel_query['opus_invoice_num']=$single_row[6];
        $set_excel_query['customer_name']=$single_row[7];
        $set_excel_query['mobile_num']=$single_row[8];
        $set_excel_query['opus_amount']=$single_row[9];
        $set_excel_query['rq4_amount']=$single_row[10];
        $set_excel_query['difference']=$single_row[11];
        $set_excel_query['ocomment']=$single_row[12];
        $set_excel_query['mark_delete']=$single_row[13];
        if($single_row[14])
        {
            $set_excel_query['upload_date']= date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($single_row[14]));
        }
        $set_excel_query_all[]=$set_excel_query;
    }

   print_r($set_excel_query_all);
```