# PHP: reading from and writing to an Excel file

Tags: php, excel

Let's say I've some data in cells A1-Ax from which I should get this data, process and write the result to the B1-Bx, C1-Cx and D1-Dx cells. Preferably using PHP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading an Excel file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look at [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

> (PHPExcel) provides a set of classes
>   for the PHP programming language,
>   which allow you to write to and read
>   from different file formats, like
>   Excel 2007, PDF, HTML, ... This
>   project is built around Microsoft's
>   OpenXML standard and PHP.

I think this is best when you have a large application written in PHP which handles excel files. I think this is not the best for very small changes.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) is really good for reading/writing excel documents (and csv files).

Used it in a lot of projects, works really well.