# Get plain text from Word [2003-2007], and Excel [2003-2007] files using PHP

Tags: php, excel, file-io, ms-word

What is the simplest way to get the plain-text only from filetypes: Word [2003-2007], and Excel  [2003-2007], using PHP on a Windows Server 2008 machine?

Theoretically, I could use the indexing service on Windows; however, I have no idea how/if that can be accessed using PHP only.

Bonus points for simplicity! Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I read Word, Excell, and PDF docs in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129018/how-do-i-read-word-excell-and-pdf-docs-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

[How do I read Word, Excell, and PDF docs in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129018/how-do-i-read-word-excell-and-pdf-docs-in-php)

or pay 35$:

http://www.phpwordlib.motion-bg.com/