# Excel file manipulation via PHP

Tags: php, excel

Can an excel file be manipulated with PHP? Can I insert certain value in certain cell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See:
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

That has all the functions you could ever need.

Sample:

> 4.5.1.    Setting a cell value by coordinate Setting a cell value by coordinate can be done using the worksheet’s setCellValue method.

```
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("05featuredemo.xlsx");    
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B8', 'Some value');
```

Comment: Thank you very much! is it free?

Comment: Yes very free. Open Source has that great trait :)

Comment: @Yogesh check their website and you'll know :). A small sidenote: depending on the level of manipulation you need, PHPEXcel might be too much or the perfect one; it's pretty big so if you just want to read, or to write to, there are other lighter alternatives (for example, a simple CSV file will be opened without problems in Excel). Check for ex. this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php) for these alternatives

Comment: Will it iclude logo PHPExcel? when I will be using or we can remove it?

Comment: @Yogesh read their website! no watermark, anyway; oh, and read the APi docs, ok? ;)

Comment: @Yogesh - PHPExcel is open-source, meaning you can actually look at the code yourself if you want to.... it's completely free to use as you wish (no restrictions for usage under a LGPL2 license), and free of charge (unless you want to donate anything to the developers as a "thank you" for their work), and isn't crippled in any way (no time limitations, or restrictions for filesize, or nasty logos appearing in your files)

Comment: @Damien Pirsy - Just for future reference, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel is a better link for alternatives for reading/writing actual Excel files, rathe rthan the CSV options.... I try to keep that list of libraries up-to-date

Comment: I deleted my comment as to not confuse people.