# Loading Excel file to a calendar-like page

Tags: php, excel, xls

I would like to read excel file (.xls) contents to a web page that will be looking like a calendar where each day will have some things set in the .xls file. I'll be doing the calendar, but I don't know from where to start on reading the excel file. Also, I want to know how to change the value of specific cells using PHP, data will be provided by user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading an Excel file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php)

Comment: A comprehensive list of the PHP libraries/tools for reading/writing Excel files can be found here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930975/alternative-for-php-excel

Answer (score 0):

I've personally never had to read excel files with PHP, but according to [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php)  post, [PHP-ExcelReader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/) is a popular option.