# Import ExcelSheet into MySql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with my project. i want to import Excel sheet directly into mysql database for PHP language without any conversion of Excel sheet into another format. i am very fed about this from last two weeks. So Please help me How I Do it. any expert please help me

Comment: Try searching in google first... U will find the first two links there itself... as first given by @Maor and other is http://rackerhacker.com/2008/11/07/importing-excel-files-into-mysql-with-php/

Comment: Do you mean that you want to store the actual Excel file itself in a database, or you want to store data from the Excel worksheets in a database table?

Comment: I want to store data from excel worksheet in a database.... actually a excel file which have 5 excel worksheets and i want to select 3 sheets to transform into database.....

Comment: read sheet by sheet and store the data you want as you parse the file !

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this question: [Reading an Excel file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php)

Read the excel file using either [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) or [PHPExcel Reader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/) (or any other preferred php lib...)

As you are reading the file, insert the data you read into your database.