# How to get Excel data into an array in PHP local site?

Tags: php, arrays, excel

How to get Excel data into an array in PHP local site. I want to print data in Excel as array in my practice site. I have created Excel in htdocs as `test.xlsx`. How can I print it's data in PHP?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php

Comment: First off, are you talking about a real xlsx file, created with MS Excel? Or simply a csv or html markup file with an extension of .xlsx?

Comment: Consider using a library like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Answer (score 1):

First include PhpExcel library into your code then use this

```
PHPExcel_IOFactory::addSearchLocation($filepath, $savedfilename);
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($filepath);

        $data = array();
        $worksheet = $objReader->getActiveSheet();
        foreach ($worksheet->getRowIterator(2) as $row) {
            $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
            $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
            foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
                $data[$cell->getRow()][$cell->getColumn()] = $cell->getValue();
            }
        }
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Or you could simply use the HTML Writer and save the output to php://output.... even fewer lines of code

Answer (score 0):

Can you please look at this link once, I think you can get more idea for your question.

http://www.phpgang.com/how-to-read-excel-file-insert-data-into-mysql-database-using-php_609.html

Comment: Link only answers aren't good answers for StackOverflow. Put the general gist of the page in your answer, and then it will stil have value here even if the linked page disappears

Comment: Also, note that the library used in that linked page will not read xlsx files, only xls files, so it won't work as an answer to this question