# Filling a Tablesorter with data

Tags: php, html, tablesorter

Has anybody got any HTML code/know if its possible to fill a table with data from a excel spreadsheet uploaded to the site directory?

I want to display a table of data on my PHP site, and wondered if it is possible to just add the data to a excel spreadsheet and update in the site directory rather than have all the information manually added as HTML rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading an Excel file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php)

Comment: The linked question is a bit older but still relevant. From how I understand the question, it's only about reading an Excel sheet in PHP and showing it as HTML, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try out Google Sheets - you can import data from Excel.

Then you can use [Sheetrock](http://chriszarate.github.io/sheetrock/).

> Sheetrock is a JavaScript library for querying, retrieving, and displaying data from Google Sheets. In other words, use a Google spreadsheet as your database! Load entire worksheets or leverage SQL-like queries to sort, group, and filter data. All you need is the URL of a public Google Sheet.

The main limitations are:

- As stated in the description. The Google Sheet needs to be *public*.
- This javascript method may not be as fast as php.

Comment: Thanks Mottie, once again!