# convert xls to html with php

Tags: php, html, excel

I am wondering if I can get some advice on folks that might have come across this before.

Basically I have a folder with files a user can add / remove which has an iframe beside it so they can view their PDF's etc.

I cannot get excel (probably ppt either) to open up in chrome or a browser.
I know I can go through google docs, or send files and get it back different format through their api but for security it is not a solution I want to work with.

example I saw in excel:
If I have a fairly loaded excel file, graph, formulas etc., in that file I 'Save As' and convert to htm I can publish option which provides a beautiful htm page with all relative pics, links in a folder.  If I can get php to do something similar this would really make my day.

I played with PHPExcel but it usually spits out a mess, sometimes just crashes because of formulas.  Unless I just haven't sent the time with PHPExcel to figure this out I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

You already know the best way use read excel file to php using any library then print the data.

if PHPExcel not working for you please have a look at following
"[Reading an Excel file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php)"

ps. if you are facing problem with PHPExcel kindly post you code in new question, definitely this great developer community will help you resolve that.

Comment: Thanks for you comments Naveed