# Excel file upload error

Tags: php, excel

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="excelfile">
<input type="submit" name="upd" value="Upload">
</form>
```

I want to upload  **sample.xls**

this is my upload script.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["upd"]))
{
$file = $_FILES['excelfile']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $c = 1;
        $heading = true;
        while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
        {
            if($heading) {
        $heading = false;
        continue;
            }
            echo "<tr><th>".$c."</th><th>".$filesop[0]."</th></tr>";
            $c = $c + 1;
        }
}
?>
```

Here is the output screenshot http://screencast.com/t/RqZWnz1y 
CSV files works correctly..
How to solve this problem?

Comment: You need to use PHPExcel.You can find the infomation there:

[https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/]
or 
you can download phpexcel and its documentation there : [https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading an Excel file in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php)

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpexcelreader/

Comment: @Manish this site on codeplex is not maintained for already 3 years. They moved to GitHub.

Comment: @dragoste Thats why i also gave github link so that he will get documentation and dowload the files.

Thanks for informing.

Comment: Yeah but i wrote it before your edit.

Comment: @dragoste Got it. Again thanks, Next time i will surely research on this before posting anything.

Answer (score 0):

CSV file is a simple **text** file. You can open it in a notepad and read the content.

XLS on the other hand is a **binary** file which means it doesn't simply contains text. Therefore you can't handle .xls files just like .txt file.

In order to handle Excel's files you can try with some ready library like [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)