# How to read Excel(.xlsx) file in php(codeigniter)?

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, phpexcel, excel-reader

I'm using **CodeIgniter** and I want to read excel file to extract data and save it to **PHPmyAdmin** database.

I've tried some third party libraries like

```
1- SimpleXLSX.class.php
2- Excel_reader
```

but these are not helping me.

Can anybody please give me a good example of how to read excel files in **CodeIgniter** efficiently?

Comment: Please go through https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Comment: I have used PHPExcel library and it is perfect for importing data from `.xls` or `.xslx` files.

Comment: check this https://arjunphp.com/how-to-use-phpexcel-with-codeigniter/

Comment: i have seen the same question , please check it, hope it will work for you too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading an Excel file in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/563670/reading-an-excel-file-in-php)

Answer (score -2):

Here is the code to read from .xlsx file in to mysql database.

```
  $csvFile = fopen("path/to/your/file");
  //skip first line
  fgetcsv($csvFile);
  //read data from csv file line by line
  while(($line = fgetcsv($csvFile)) !== FALSE){        
     //You can have your active record's query to insert it into Db
     $db->query("INSERT INTO tableName (Column1) VALUES ('".$line[0]."')");
  }                
  //close opened csv file
  fclose($csvFile);
```

Comment: `fgetcsv()` will ___not___ read from a native BIFF (xls) or OfficeOpenXML (xlsx) format file, only from basic CSV files